# Spring Boot Mockito - @InjectMocks - How to mock selected dependencies only

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a `@Service` called `UserServiceImpl` that depends on two other beans. One is the `UserRepository` bean and the other is a bean called `SessionService`.

My requirement is during tests of the UserServiceImpl class, I must be able to inject a mock  of the `SessionService` dependency, but keep the `UserRepository` dependency as it is.

My service class that looks like this:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionService sessionService;
    
    
    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        log.info("User Creation at Service");
        // ... Do some validations .. //

        // This needs to be mocked in Unit Tests
        String returnValue = sessionService.doSomethingThatIDontWantInTests(); 

        user.setInternalKey(returnValue);

        // .. Do some more Validations .. //

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now, here is my Test Class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;
    
    @Mock
    private SessionService sessionService;
    
    
    @Test
    void CreateUserTest() {
        Mockito.when(sessionService.doSomethingThatIDontWantInTests()).thenReturn("abcxyz123321");
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John Doe");
        user.setEmail("john.doe@example.com");
        User savedUser = userService.create(user);
        
        assertNotNull(savedUser.getUserId());

    }
}
```

When I run this test, Mockito successfully mocks the `SessionService` call. But, `UserServiceImpl.createUser()` still fails with the message saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.myproject.data.repos.UserRepository.save(User)" because "this.userRepository" is null
```

Should I inject `UserRepository` also as a mock and use Mockito to mock the `UserRepository.save()` method?

I would like to mock only the `SessionService` dependency, and not the `UserRepository` dependency.

Is it something doable? If so, how? Please advise.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing different testing styles.

**Style 1 - spring integration test**

This is when Spring Boot creates the beans in its context, and you inject them to your test class.

- use `@SpringBootTest`
- use `@Autowired` to inject beans to your test
- use `@MockBean` to replace beans in Spring contexts by mocks

**Style 2 - Unit test**

This does not use Spring DI. In this style, it is typical to mock all dependencies.

- use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`
- annotate dependencies as `@Mock`
- annotate SUT with `@InjectMocks`

Using real dependencies is also possible, but in that case you need to construct SUT manually - Mockito does not support partial injections.

Unit tests tend to be much more lightweight and less brittle, on the other hand integration tests cover a large chunk of the app.

Note that if `UserRepository` is a spring-data repo, it cant be created manually.

Answer (score -1):

You must use a `@SpyBean` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html), which will inject the original bean but which you can verify the calls and arguments.